# Calculate Z Median from 3d line?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, ogr, 3d

How does one calculate the **median** value of Z from a 3D line?

The [Add Surface Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) tool in 3D Analyst only does Min,Max and Mean (average), and requires a surface model. (In this case I have one, but all necessary info is in the line, so let's just use that.) [Line Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/line-statistics.htm) can do Median as well as Minority, Majority and a few others, but it doesn't know about 3D lines and only operates on field attributes.

Primary environment is ArcGIS Desktop but I'm open to Gdal/Qgis methods that write results to the source feature class in place (file-gdb).

Desired outcome are lines with a populated Z_Median attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolate shapes using tool from 3d analyst.
Run field calculator expression on numeric field type float, parser - Python

```
def getMedian(shp):
    aList=[]
    part=shp.getPart(0)
    n=len(part)
    for i in xrange(n):
        p=part.getObject(i)
        z=p.Z
        aList.append(z)
    aList.sort()
    return aList[n/2]
```

To call it use:

```
getMedian(!Shape!)
```

It will work on a single part 3D polylines

Comment: This is near perfect, thanks (though indentation screwed me up for awhile. I'd put aList.append in parent). I changed it to [use `numpy.median()`](https://gist.github.com/maphew/e7ed7b8a462c48892c7b) so I didn't have to add logic to handle when the list has even number of items. Those with ArcGIS Pro can use `statistics.median()` instead ('cause python 3). Good python + median reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python

Comment: This will fail on a polygon interior ring (_"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Z'"_). This seems to work: `p=part.getObject(i); if p: z=p.Z`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [Add Z Information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-z-information.htm) tool.

Comment: It's not appreciably different from Add Surface Information tool, providing only min,max and mean statistics.